# Why the behavior of Convert.ToString(object as null) vs Convert.ToString(string as null)

Tags: c#

I have created a console application to analyze the behavior of

```
Convert.ToString()
```

, i know `Convert.ToString()` do not cause exception, but in terms of object it initialize the return string as empty, however in case of string it remains null.

```
string s = null;
object obj = null;
string objec = Convert.ToString(obj);//it return an empty string
string ss = Convert.ToString(s);// it returns ss=null
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: please share your exact question.

Comment: i think his question is why is the behaviour of this different when they both are reference types and stored on the heap

Comment: Those are two different overloads and the one that takes strings just returns whatever you passed in.  I think the `string` overload just exists to handle the case when someone actually passes a `string` which is kinda pointless and should just be a no-op.

Comment: Though I do think that it would make more since of the `object` overload to return `null` for a `null` input because if something is `null` or unknown then it's string representation should also be `null` or unknown.  But I'm guessing it was done to avoid null reference exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at their compiled assemblies the program looks like this

```
        string s = null;
        Convert.ToString(null); //1
        Convert.ToString(s);  // 2
```

the first `ToString` Returns `""`  string because it checks the following condition

```
         if (value == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

and the second `ToString` returns null because it executes following method

```
 public static string ToString(string value)
        {
            return value;
        }
```

it looks confusing because `ToString` is same on both statements but actually they both are working differently. The first `ToString` function calls the ToSting of `Object Type` and the second `ToString` function calls ToString of `String Type`